# NoMethodError / validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I am using an if statement to either pull the user name from @current_user.name (adauth) if the form is new, and @complaint.user.name if the form is being edited.

The validations were working but now, if I try to submit an empty form or a form where an associated field value is nil, then I get an error of

```
NoMethodError in Complaints#create
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints/app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb where line #27 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/complaints/new.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:27:in `block in _app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__838826376_68516916'
app/views/complaints/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_complaints__form_html_erb__838826376_68516916'
app/views/complaints/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_complaints_new_html_erb__529765002_56812308'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:135:in `create'
```

_form.html.erb for complaints (where i have the conditional code)

```
   <strong>Originator:</strong><br>

          <!-- Below will show the user name. If it is not a new complaint, we pull the user name from the complaint table
           Otherwise, we get the name of the currently logged in user.  -->

          <% if action_name != "new" then %>
              <%=  @user.name %>
          <% else %>
              <%= @current_user.name %>
                  <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => @current_user.id) %>
          <% end %>


        </td>
```

Line 27 is `<%=  @user.name %>`  I think that what is happening is that the reload after a failed validation is no longer an action of 'new'. How can I fix this?

```
 validates_presence_of :status
  validates_presence_of :sales_order
  validates_presence_of :product_name
  validates_presence_of :coater_roll_number
  validates_presence_of :coater_work_order
  validates_presence_of :slitter_disposition
  validates_presence_of :length
  validates_presence_of :measure
  validates_presence_of :disposition
  validates_presence_of :reason_for_complaint
  validates_presence_of :customer
```

I think what is happening is that when the form is reloaded after failing a validation, it no longer is a controller action of 'new'.

Comment: Where do you set the `@user`? Make sure it's populated with a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

This error simply means that your `@user` is `nil` and that's why it's failing on `<%=  @user.name %>`. Make sure your `@user` has the value and is not not `nil`. Then, it will work.

You can also try using [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) like this: `<%= @user.try(:name) %>`. That way, your program will not crash when `@user` is nil. But, the best way is to find out why `@user` is nil and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when a validation fails, the action shifts from NEW to CREATE. The code below will show the @current_user.name for NEW and CREATE actions and the @user.name from the table for edit actions.

```
  <% if action_name != "new" && action_name != "create" then %>
      <%=  @user.name %>
  <% else %>
      <%= @current_user.name %>
          <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => @current_user.id) %>
  <% end %>
```